# kate editor with built-in terminal

Tags: macos, terminal, text-editor

For programming it is very convenient to have a built-in terminal inside a text editor. Therefore my favorite text editor on KDE-Linux is kate which has great ability of a built-in terminal below the text which is synchronized with the text path. Navigating through the open files and do terminal commands with them is then extremely easy.

I have installed kate via macport on OS X 10.10, but the terminal does not appear even though it shows its icon. Any idea if this a a kate bug or 10.10? If kate is not fully compatible with OS, is there any other text editor on Mac with a built-in terminal?

Thanks!

Comment: I found the solution and the problem with kate is explained here: https://trac.macports.org/wiki/KDE and based on it one has to launch Kbuildsycoca. Then the terminal appears, but still kate on OS is not as robust as on Linux.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about Kate, but with emacs you can do : `Alt + X - Shell` and you have a terminal inside a text editor inside a terminal :)

https://www.masteringemacs.org/article/running-shells-in-emacs-overview

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much! I found however how to fix kate to show the terminal.

Comment: So you don't join the emacs cult ? :( Outch'

Comment: emacs always has been tricky for me..never really tried it :)